# Syntax Error With Comma in Table Creation

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I'm trying to create a table in SQL Server with the following code:

```
CREATE TABLE LEARNERS
(
    Id int NOT NULL Primary Key,
    LastName varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    FirstName varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    Marital_Status char(1) DEFAULT 'S',
    Address varchar(255),
    Email varchar(255),
    Parish varchar(50),

    CONSTRAINT chk_LEARNERS CHECK (Id > 0 
                                   AND Parish in ('Kingston','St. Cathrine','Portland','St.Andrew'),
    CONSTRAINT chk_Person_Marital CHECK (Marital_status = 'S' or Marital_Status = 'M'),
    CONSTRAINT uk_email UNIQUE (Email),
)
```

But there is a red line suggesting an error right below the comma at the end of this line

```
CONSTRAINT chk_LEARNERS CHECK (Id > 0 AND Parish IN ('Kingston','St. Cathrine','Portland','St.Andrew'),
```

The error that came up is:

> Incorrect Syntax Error near ','. Expecting ')', AND, or OR.

I can't seem to find the error. What could be the cause of this and how can I resolve this issue?

Comment: First find out if you're using MySQL or SQL Server, as the syntax isn't exactly the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two errors:

1. Missing `closing parenthesis` in `CONSTRAINT chk_LEARNERS CHECK (Id>0 AND Parish in ('Kingston','St. Cathrine','Portland','St.Andrew'),`
2. Extra `comma` before closing parenthesis of create table.

Answer (score 1):

Missing `close Parenthesis` in check constraint

```
CONSTRAINT chk_LEARNERS CHECK 
    (Id>0 AND Parish IN ('Kingston', 'St. Cathrine', 'Portland', 'St.Andrew')), --here
```